# specify java string length

Tags: java, string

Ho do i specify the entered string to be between 30 and 60 characters?I tried the following but i get illegal start of expression error at (if) line.

```
public class Manipulation {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // let the user enter a string
    OOPHelper.print("Please enter a string: ");
    String s = OOPHelper.readKeyboardString();

    if (s.length >=30) && (s.length <=60){
        OOPHelper.println(s);
    }
    else
```

Answer (score 10):

You have a syntax error. Try...

```
if ( s.length() >=30 && s.length() <= 60) { ...
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems:

1. In an `if`, the contents of the test-expression have to wrapped in `(...)`. So, `if (...) && (...)` needs to be changed to `if ((...) && (...))`.
2. `length` is a public method, not a public field, so it needs to be called with parentheses. So, `s.length` needs to be changed to `s.length()`.

Putting it together — change this line:

```
if (s.length >=30) && (s.length <=60){
```

to this:

```
if (s.length() >= 30 && s.length() <= 60) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement should be, like

```
if (s.length() >= 30 && s.length() <= 60)
{
   OOPHelper.println(s);
}
```